# BigQuery - Replace whitespace in string

Tags: google-bigquery

My hair is going grey over here. I have a table with a column where i want to remove the whitespace.
Expected result: "8 800 000 kr" -> "8800000kr"

I can't get this to work. Please see query output below:

**Image removed by the author because it contained explicit language.**

Why is the white space not removed?

When i perform the query against mock data it works:
[image]

What could be wrong with the string in the first example? Everywhere i look i looks identical to the mocked string in example 2.

Comment: Fina variabelnamn :-(

Comment: Tack! Dom speglar ungefär hur bra jag mår just nu

Comment: what does `select to_code_points(slutpris)` returns? You might have a string that is not UTF8. Try experimenting with `SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING` as well.

Comment: show result in JSON tab - it usually helps to understand what really text is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL and explains your problem

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 'with spaces' space_type, '8 800 000 kr' slutpris union all
  select 'with non-breaking spaces', replace('8 800 000 kr', chr(32), chr(160)) slutpris
)
select space_type, slutpris,
  replace(slutpris, ' ', ''),
  regexp_replace(slutpris, r'\s', ''),
  regexp_replace(slutpris, r'\s|kr', '') 
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]

So, as you can see - non-breaking space is not recognized as a space character or any white space

Forgot to mention possible solution -

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 'with spaces' space_type, '8 800 000 kr' slutpris union all
  select 'with non-breaking spaces', replace('8 800 000 kr', chr(32), chr(160)) slutpris
)
select space_type, slutpris,
  translate(slutpris, chr(32) || chr(160), ''),
  regexp_replace(slutpris, '[\u00A0\\s]', ''),
  regexp_replace(slutpris, '[\u00A0\\s]|kr', '')
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]