# CAST a column contain empty cells, NULL and String to FLOAT64 in BigQuery

Tags: sql, casting, google-bigquery

I am encountering a problem with casting strings to float that I haven't been able to solve. I have a column in a BQ table contain values (numbers as string), NULLs adn empty cells. Now, I want to CAST the values to FLOAT64 but I get a double value error. I tried:

```
CAST(myfield AS FLOAT64) as myfield
```

and thinking it might help to replace empty field by NULL:

```
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(myfield, " ", NULL) AS FLOAT64 ) as myfield
```

But this sets everything to NULL.

Any idea on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which string value is causing the error?

Comment: I am unsure. The column has numbers as strings, empty and NULL.

Comment: Does the error contain the string value that triggers the error?

Comment: Just says ```Bad double value:```

Comment: Ok so yes, it **is** some whitespace... perhaps two spaces or may be a tab. Try replacing the pattern `^ +$` with nulls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a comment you made to another question, it is clear that spaces are not your only problem in your data.

You need to identify and fix the problem data *(which should ideally be done before ingestion in to the database, but that's a different question)*.

For example, you could use `safe_cast()`:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#safe_casting

`SAFE_CAST()` doesn't throw an error, instead it returns `NULL`, so you can just check for those `NULL`s...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
      myfield IS NOT NULL
  AND SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(myfield, ' ', '') AS FLOAT64) IS NULL
```

Or, just use the `SAFE_CAST()` in your query *(instead of `CAST()`)* and accept that badly formed data will yield a `NULL`

- That prevents runtime errors
- But 'hides' bad data as `NULL`s

***EDIT:***

Also, you can make your `REPLACE()` more robust by stripping other white space characters too *(such as tabs, carriage returns, etc)*.

- [BigQuery - Replace whitespace in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721322/bigquery-replace-whitespace-in-string)

Answer (score 0):

To remove characters from a string, use an empty string, not `NULL`:

```
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(myfield, ' ', '') AS FLOAT64 ) as myfield
```

`REGEXP_REPLACE()` is overkill for this operation.  You can just use regular `REPLACE()`:

```
CAST(REPLACE(myfield, ' ', '') AS FLOAT64 ) as myfield
```

Comment: I still get the ```double value``` error with this approach.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes - Then spaces in the strings aren't your only problem.